# Numba: LLVM IR parsing error when trying to access elements in a typed list of jitted functions

Tags: python-3.x, llvm, numba

I'm encountering an issue with Numba when trying to access elements in a typed list of jitted functions. The error message I receive is an "LLVM IR parsing error" with the line **`ret i8* null`**.

Here's a simplified code snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
import numba
from numba import njit, types
import numpy as np

@njit
def f1(vars, opts):
    x, y = vars
    opt1 = opts[0]
    return (x + y) * opt1

@njit
def f2(vars, opts):
    x, y = vars
    opt1, opt2 = opts
    return (2 * x + y) * opt1 * opt2

# Define the function type
func_type = types.float64(types.float64[:], types.float64[:]).as_type()

# Create a typed list to hold the function pointers
f_list = numba.typed.List.empty_list(func_type)
f_list.append(f1)
f_list.append(f2)

@njit
def dump(l):
    for i, f in enumerate(l):
        print(i, f)

dump(f_list)
```

When I run the **`dump`** function, I get the following error:

```
LLVM IR parsing error
<string>:457:7: error: value doesn't match function result type 'i32'
  ret i8* null
```

At the same time in python mode

```
for i, f in enumerate(f_list):
    print(i,f)
```

it works as expected.

I've already updated Numba to the latest version, but the issue persists.

```
Python 3.9.12
llvmlite-0.40.1 
numba-0.57.1
```

Any insights into what might be causing this and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue to print string representation of the function type (e.g. not pass the function dirrectly to python function `print()`, but convert it to string first):

```py
import numba
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, types


@njit
def f1(vars, opts):
    x, y = vars
    opt1 = opts[0]
    return (x + y) * opt1


@njit
def f2(vars, opts):
    x, y = vars
    opt1, opt2 = opts
    return (2 * x + y) * opt1 * opt2


# Define the function type
func_type = types.float64(types.float64[:], types.float64[:]).as_type()

# Create a typed list to hold the function pointers
f_list = numba.typed.List.empty_list(func_type)
f_list.append(f1)
f_list.append(f2)


@njit
def dump(l):
    a = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.float64)
    b = np.array([3, 4], dtype=np.float64)

    for i, f in enumerate(l):
        print(i, f"{f}")
        print(f(a, b))


dump(f_list)
```

Prints:

```
0 <object type:FunctionType[float64(array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, A))]>
9.0
1 <object type:FunctionType[float64(array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, A))]>
48.0
```